# Displaying a number in 2 point decimal format in jsf

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, converters

I am using JSF 2 and RichFaces 3. Here in the picture shown below, numbers are being displayed as what they are in the database.

[image]

But I want to display them as `6749395.20` if fraction part is there and `5095138.00` if no fraction part is there.

As of now I have tried something like this.

```html
 <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Total Amount"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{rr[2]}">
        <f:convertNumber type="number" groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2" pattern="#0.00"/>
    </h:outputText>
 </rich:column>
```

Actually I am showing all of them together, but I have tried with all of them as all possible combinations with `type`, `groupingUsed`, `minFractionDigits` and `pattern`.

Why does it not work? How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Your converter should work as expected. The `minFractionDigits="2"` should be enough. Did you try the same outside the dataTable?

Comment: ya man I tried it outside the datatable also, but the main problem was datatype and thanks to @BalusC, He helped me out.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That can happen if the value is not a [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) at all, for example a `String`. You're then basically using the wrong type for the data it represents. To represent currencies in Java, you should be using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Also, make sure that the type in the database table is right, i.e. it should not be a varchar, but a decimal.

Once you've fixed the data type, then the `<f:convertNumber>` will work as you told it to do. Note that the `pattern` attribute will override the `groupingUsed` and `minFractionDigits`. You should use either the `pattern` **or** the others. Also, `type="number"` is already the default, so it can be removed.

So, either use

```html
<f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
```

or

```html
<f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" minFractionDigits="2" />
```

Note that they generate different formats. You probably want to set grouping to `false`.

You can also use `type="currency"`, it will then automatically apply the right pattern as per the `UIViewRoot#getLocale()`:

```html
<f:convertNumber type="currency" />
```

See also the [tag library documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertNumber.html) and the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) javadoc.

Comment: actually in my database they were numbers and i was fetching them in string and then was trying to display them as number with some pattern. Now I have changed it to an arraylist. and now it is displaying the correct and desired format.     Thanks Buddy Thanks a lot................

Comment: And with name currency, is there any method which I can display INR symbol along with rupee like I CAN display Dollar($) symbol.