# how to format double in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to format some double variables like " 12.0 , 13.5 ". i just  want to show 12.0 as 12. 13.5 as 13.5 . I have tried f:convertNumber tags . Also tried `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412908/displaying-a-number-in-2-point-decimal-format-in-jsf` this.  I have using p:inputNumber for trying " minValue="0" thousandSeparator="" decimalSeparator="." decimalPlaces="0" " these But i dont get that what i want. I dont want to make my own converter to do.  can i do without being create converter class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `minFractionDigits` when you tried `f:convertNumber`?

For instance:

```
<f:convertNumber  pattern="#0.000" minFractionDigits="0"/>
```

In addition, maybe you wanna have a key filter as well:

```
<p:keyFilter mask="pnum"/>
```